# Next-auth - use Accounts table just for access_token to call OAuth APIs without registering new Users?

Tags: next.js, oauth-2.0, prisma, next-auth

I have usual next-auth Prisma schema like in this example:

https://github.com/prisma/prisma-examples/blob/latest/typescript/rest-nextjs-api-routes-auth/prisma/schema.prisma

```
model Account {
  id                 Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  userId             Int     @map("user_id")
  type               String
  provider           String
  providerAccountId  String  @map("provider_account_id")
  refresh_token      String?
  access_token       String?
  expires_at         Int?
  token_type         String?
  scope              String?
  id_token           String?
  session_state      String?
  oauth_token_secret String?
  oauth_token        String?
  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])
  @@map("accounts")
}

model User {
  id            Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
  emailVerified DateTime? @map("email_verified")
  image         String?
  createdAt     DateTime  @default(now()) @map(name: "created_at")
  updatedAt     DateTime  @updatedAt @map(name: "updated_at")
  posts         Post[]
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
  @@map(name: "users")
}
```

I have custom OAuth provider and when user "signs in" with it I just want to store his access_token (and other tokens) in Accounts table and use it to make API calls on his behalf without registering new a new User. I use separate credentials provider for register and sign in.

**What is the best place to prevent new user creation in User table and to just update Accounts table with tokens and a reference to the existing User entry?**

Some possible places that come into my mind are userinfo request() callback, createUser and linkAccount events. Or I must implement custom database adapter just for this?

https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers/oauth#userinfo-option

https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/events#createuser

Any useful advice or existing example are appreciated.